# How to get route arguments of parent routes?

Tags: flutter

A bit simplified, my app routes have three levels of nesting:

```
/profile
  /course
    /quiz
```

These are represented by named routes, `/profile`, `/profile/course` and `/profile/course/quiz`. These routes map to widgets: `ProfileScreen`, `CourseScreen` and `QuizScreen`. Each of these takes an argument: the `Profile`, `Course` and `Quiz` model objects, respectively.

If I understand correctly, the `Navigator` will ensure that parent routes will always be on the stack before child routes, so when we're on the `/profile/course/quiz` route, we'll have `/profile/course` above that.

**Now I'm inside the `QuizScreen` widget, and I want to access the current `Course`. How do I do that?**

It's somewhere on the route stack, but `ModalRoute.of(context)` will of course give me the `/profile/course/quiz` route, not the `/profile/course` route, so `ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments` will be a `Quiz`.

I tried wrapping the `CourseScreen` in a `Provider<Course>` widget (from the excellent `providers` package) which provides the `Course` down to child widgets, but sub-routes actually become sibling widgets, not children.

Of course I could explicitly pass the `Course` down to the `/profile/course/quiz` route as a second argument (wrapped together with the `Quiz` in an array or object), but this seems needlessly convoluted and doesn't scale well.

Is there a way to get the route arguments of a parent route? Or does this actually indicate that I'm doing it wrong and should be designing my app differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Of course I could explicitly pass the `Course` down to the `/profile/course/quiz` route as a second argument (wrapped together with the `Quiz` in an array or object), but this seems needlessly convoluted and doesn't scale well.

I found a compelling argument for this approach after all: testability. It means that the `QuizScreen` can be tested independently of all the other screens and even the routing system.

So I created a simple class to hold the arguments:

```dart
class QuizScreenArgs {
  final Course course;
  final Quiz quiz;

  QuizScreenArgs(this.course, this.quiz);
}
```

Then I realized I can take this one step further and make each route a class:

```dart
class QuizRoute extends MaterialRoute<QuizResult> {
  QuizRoute(Course course, Quiz quiz) : super
}
```

This has the advantage that both the route arguments and the route's return type are explicitly typed. No more `ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as IHopeThisIsWhatWasPassed` or `(await Navigator.of(...).pushNamed(...)) as IHopeThisIsWhatWasReturned`.

It needs to be a class (rather than just a factory method) so we can use `Navigator.popUntil`:

```
Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route is CourseRoute);
```

All in all, I'm quite happy with this approach and I'm surprised that the docs don't recommend or even hint at this possibility.